# problema al correr mi proyecto flutter teniendo google_maps_flutter

Tags: flutter, google-maps

hola a todos estoy haciendo una app tipo uber y estoy implementando google_maps_flutter pero al instalarlo con flutter pub add google_maps_flutter me sale la versión ^2.5.3 y al correr mi proyecto en mi celular poco x3 pro ya que lo uso como device me sale un error de un sdk que debe ser mas alto llevo una semana estancado porque todo lo que hago no funciona , este es el error :[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Y ya intentaste usar el mismo paquete en una versión mayor? ¿Hiciste lo que el mensaje te dice?

Answer (score 0):

El uso de `google_maps_flutter` te exige que la `minSdkVersion` sea 20, te recomiendo hacer lo siguiente:
Ve al archivo `<proyecto>/android/app/build.gradle`

Y cambia lo siguiente:

```
android {
  // compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
  compileSdkVersion 34
  ...
  defaultConfig {
    ...
    // minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
    minSdkVersion 20
    ...
  }
}
```